# Issue with cold water valve - kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I have an odd plumbing issue.

When I open the cold water valve under the kitchen sink, it causes the cold water to automatically come out of the faucet, without having to move the kitchen sink handle (*right side*).

Normally, you open the valve, and then you turn the kitchen sink handle and water comes out.

I can't get the water to stop by using the handle, however. It would run continuously (*cold water*) if I didn't completely close the cold water valve.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: We can not even begin to guess without knowing the kind/brand/model of faucet.  It may be repairable or not.

Comment: It's a two handle Moen faucet...

Comment: Did this just start happening or has it been going on for a while?

Comment: Your faucet's cold-side valve is malfunctioning and needs repair. That's about all you will get without more detail about how the problem manifested, and detail about your faucet.